# Post method with bearer token show error RequestGuard::getUser does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have installed passport and everything works fine from getting user token and registering and logging in ,
I cannot store order by token in my order model

here is my api routing

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' => 
'api.'], function () {
       Route::post('userLogin','UserController@UserLogin');
       Route::post('userRegister','UserController@UserRegister');

       Route::get('/orders/{orders}', 'OrdersController@show')- >name('orders.show');

       Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
       Route::post('/cities', 'CitiesController@store')- >name('CitiesController.store');   
       Route::post('/orders', 'OrdersController@store')- >name('OrdersController.store');

       Route::get('userDetails','UserController@UserDetails');
       Route::get('orders','OrdersController@index');
});
```

here is my order model

```
 <?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Traits\FilterByUser;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class Order
 *
 * @package App
 * @property integer $order_no
 * @property string $user
 * @property string $vendor
 * @property string $status
 * @property string $details
 * @property string $service_date
 * @property decimal $price
 * @property string $created_by
 */
class Order extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, FilterByUser , HasApiTokens;

protected $fillable = ['order_no', 'details', 'service_date', 'price', 'user_id', 'vendor_id', 'status_id', 'created_by_id'];
protected $hidden = [];

//Saad Edited here on april 30 
//added random order number 

public static function boot()
{

    parent::boot();


            static::creating(function($model){
                $random_code = null;
                while($random_code === null){
                    $tmp_random_code = rand(100000, 999999);
                    if(!self::where('order_no', $tmp_random_code)->count()){
                        $random_code = $tmp_random_code;
                    }
                }
                $model->order_no = $random_code;
            });
}

/**
 * Set attribute to money format
 * @param $input
 */
public function setOrderNoAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['order_no'] = $input ? $input : null;
}


/**
 * Set to null if empty
 * @param $input
 */
public function setStatusIdAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['status_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
}

/**
 * Set attribute to date format
 * @param $input
 */
public function setServiceDateAttribute($input)
{
    if ($input != null && $input != '') {
        $this->attributes['service_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
    } else {
        $this->attributes['service_date'] = null;
    }
}

/**
 * Get attribute from date format
 * @param $input
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getServiceDateAttribute($input)
{
    $zeroDate = str_replace(['Y', 'm', 'd'], ['0000', '00', '00'], config('app.date_format'));

    if ($input != $zeroDate && $input != null) {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $input)->format(config('app.date_format'));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

/**
 * Set attribute to money format
 * @param $input
 */
public function setPriceAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['price'] = $input ? $input : null;
}

/**
 * Set to null if empty
 * @param $input
 */
public function setCreatedByIdAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['created_by_id'] = $input ? $input : null;
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function vendor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'vendor_id');
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Status::class, 'status_id')->withTrashed();
}

public function created_by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by_id');
}

}
```

and here is my store function in ordercontroller

```
public function store(StoreOrdersRequest $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $order = Order::create($request->all());
        $order->user_id=$user->id;
        $order->save();
        return response()->json($order);

    }
```

I want my post method to be protected by auth:api and store user id that matches the token in user_id in order model and successfully store new order

Comment: change `'as' => 'api.'` to `'as' => 'api'`

Comment: have you tried changing `auth::user()` to  `auth()->guard('api')->user();`

Comment: not working both